# Repeater Retrieve the previous index Property value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the Repeater control in Asp.net.

I have scenario where based on the condition i have to Retrieve the previous index Property value.

Please, help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DataSource is available when databinding the repeater, you could do something like this:

Datasource defintion just for showing an example:

```
protected DataTable Data
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["Data"] == null)
        { 
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Color");
            table.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(int));

            table.Rows.Add(1, "Ball", "Red", 10);
            table.Rows.Add(2, "Table", "Black", 50);
            table.Rows.Add(3, "Chair", "Green", 30);
            ViewState["Data"] = table;
        }
        return (DataTable)ViewState["Data"];
    }
}
```

Page Load (Repeater DataBinding):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rpt.DataSource = Data;
    rpt.DataBind();
}
```

Repeater Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# 
            Condition ? Data.Rows[Container.ItemIndex - 1]["Name"] : Eval("Name")
        %> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`Data` references the protected property on the code-behind, which is a DataTable.